# C# Loading dates from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, save

I have a program that is saves information like a list of names, file paths, summary, and dates.

Everything saves ok and everything load ok from the file... except if I load the information in from the file, don't make any changes and re-save the file again and reload, the first date seems to get corrupted somehow. I edit the xml file in an editor and it all seems to be ok. I have to alter the first date on the list and re-save in the editor. Then it will load ok.

Here is my save code for the date portion only:

```
            using (XmlWriter serializer = XmlWriter.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
            {

                serializer.Flush();
                serializer.WriteStartDocument();
                serializer.WriteStartElement("Items");

                serializer.WriteElementString("DRNumber", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
                serializer.WriteElementString("PicsPath", textBox3.Text.ToString());
                serializer.WriteElementString("DocPath", textBox4.Text.ToString());

            foreach (DateTime fname in date)
                {
                    serializer.WriteElementString("Date", fname.ToShortDateString());

                }
                serializer.WriteEndElement();

                serializer.WriteEndDocument();
                serializer.Flush();
                serializer.Close();
                FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
```

Is this the best way to write dates to an XML, or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the way the xml file is being constructed.  perhaps post an example of the xml file that has the "corrupted" date?

Comment: When you save data to file is it being saved ok (check file content)? If you manually make good xml and load it, is it being loaded ok?

Comment: I agree with the above comments, I cant see anything wrong with what you are doing... check the saving / loading portion of the code - it is more than likely something wrong there.

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` is culture-sensitive. Do you trying to read resulting XML on the same machine under the same user who produced it? If the answer is no or your program runs under other user's credentials (e.g. as windows service under SYSTEM account) - it could be the case.

Comment: The XML file is actually being made by the program, and it saves good. It opens in an external editor fine. It loads good as well and its fine as long as you alter the data in the program (or external XML editor). But if you load it and re-save it without making any changes it won't load properly the first set of values.

Comment: As a side note: `TextBox1.Text` already **is** a string - there's absolutely no point in calling `.ToString()` on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) or [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) APIs

```
XElement root = new XElement("Root",new XElement("Child", "child content"));
root.Save("Root.xml");
```

Comment: How would you go about adding an array list using xelement? I tried the following but I get only one date from the list:

`foreach (DateTime fname in date)
                    {

                        XElement root = new XElement("Root", new XElement("Date", fname.ToShortDateString()));
                        root.Save("c:\\temp pic\\test.xml");`

Comment: Never Mind I found it using **root.Add**.

Comment: Aaannnddd it looks like XElement was the way to go! It is working properly! Thank you!!